# Use Excel VBA If value in column a is not in column b then add value to column c

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

```
Dim i As Variant
    'For i = 1 To 5
     For Each i In rngWatch
     Dim c As Variant
     c = rngWatch.Cells(i, 1).Value
     If i <> rngReconcile.Cells(i, 1).Value Then


        MsgBox i

        End If

        Next i
```

The above for loop and if statement is where I am lost. If a value from `rngwatch` is not in `rngreconcile` then I would like to add the value to a new range (yet to be defined)

```
Sub Client_Dirty_Recon()

Dim Client_path As String
Dim Client_watchlist As Workbook
Dim Client_client_email As Workbook
Set Client_watchlist = ActiveWorkbook
Dim email_range As Range
Dim watchlist_range As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbDirty As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'optional - screen will not flash

Client_path = Range("Path")
Workbooks.Open Client_path
Dim recon_list As Range
Set wbDirty = Workbooks.Open(Client_path)
Dim rngReconcile As Range
Dim rngWatch As Range
Set rngReconcile = wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:K")
Set rngWatch = wbDirty.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")



Dim i As Variant
    'For i = 1 To 5
     For Each i In rngWatch
     Dim c As Variant
     c = rngWatch.Cells(i, 1).Value
     If i <> rngReconcile.Cells(i, 1).Value Then


        MsgBox i

        End If

        Next i

ActiveWindow.Close Savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice question. What exactly do you want? Is your VBA not working or do you want to do it without VBA? To quote your question "__If value in column a is not in column b then add value to column c__" Which value should be added to col. C??

Comment: A for loop and or if statement? that which scans through rngWatch to see if a value in this range is NOT if rngReconcile, if the value is in rngWatch is NOT in rngReconcile then add that unique value to  a new range (i.e. column c of wb)

Comment: You're just trying to shake out uniques?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to shake out uniques via this VBA procedure

Comment: grrr.... didn't see the "ActiveWindow.Close Savechanges:=False" at the end, and the last 10min of scripting got wiped...

Comment: So what's the problem? What happens? What should happen? Any errors? Where? Why can't you use proven unique identification methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment that ideally you'd like two workbooks here is an updated description and code:

1. The *Active Workbook*, which has a Named range with the **path** of **another** workbook with the *Watch* list (*wb*)  Note: You could use either Client_watchlist (ActiveWorkbook) or wb (ThisWorkbook)
2. The same workbook has the code module, which has the *Reconcile* list - existing values to compare the new values to (*wb*)
3. The workbook with the *Watch* list - the new values to be compared - the location being specified in the *Active Workbook* above (*wbDirty*)
4. The *Active Workbook* contains the *Watch* values that don't exist in the *Reconcile* list.

   - You no longer need a Named Range in the *Active Workbook* named *ResultPath*.
   - Completely took out the compiler variable.
5. The *Active Workbook* must be open, and the other workbook must exist , but **not** be open. You could, of course, put error checking in to see if it is already open.
6. Since you changed the ScreenUpdating property, I put in the matching reset at the bottom (this can cause lots of panic if not reset!). Also put in some status updates. May not be necessary if it runs quickly enough.
7. Finally, I used the Application.WorksheetFunction.Match function to scan for the existing values in the "Reconcile" list. In my tests, that ran about 7 times faster than cycling through the list, checking for each value individually, but that may vary depending on the type of data and how many values there are.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   '#Const NewRangeInActiveWorkbook = False

   Sub Client_Dirty_Recon()

   Dim nRow As Long                        ' Last filled cell in column
   Dim c As Range                          ' rngWatch.Cells(i, 1).Value
   Dim oldStatusBar As Variant             ' Save StatusBar status
   'Dim Client_watchlist As Workbook        ' ActiveWorkbook
   Dim Client_path As String               ' Range("Path")
   'Dim New_path As String                  ' Range("ResultPath")
   Dim wb As Workbook                      ' ThisWorkbook
   Dim wbDirty As Workbook                 ' Workbooks.Open(Client_path)
   'Dim wbNew As Workbook                   ' Result of compare
   Dim rngReconcile As Range               ' wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:K")
   Dim rngWatch As Range                   ' wbDirty.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
   Dim rngNew As Range                     ' wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")

   oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar     'optional - save StatusBar
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = True             'optional - turn on StatusBar
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False              'optional - screen won't flash
   Application.StatusBar = "Opening workbooks..."  'optional - Update user

   'Set Client_watchlist = ActiveWorkbook
   'Client_path = Client_watchlist.Names("Path").RefersToRange.Value

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Client_path = wb.Names("Path").RefersToRange.Value
   ' Get only used part of column
   Set rngReconcile = wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:K")
   nRow = rngReconcile(rngReconcile.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row   ' Get last filled cell
   Set rngReconcile = Range(rngReconcile(1), rngReconcile(nRow)) ' Reduce rng size

   Set wbDirty = Workbooks.Open(Client_path)   ' Assumes it exists and is not open
   ' Get only used part of column
   Set rngWatch = wbDirty.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
   nRow = rngWatch(rngWatch.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row     ' Get last filled cell
   Set rngWatch = Range(rngWatch(1), rngWatch(nRow))       ' Reduce range size

   '#If NewRangeInActiveWorkbook Then
   '    Set wbNew = Client_watchlist  ' Change #Const above to assign to existing wb
   '#Else
   '    New_path = Client_watchlist.Names("ResultPath").RefersToRange.Value
   '    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(New_path) ' Assumes it exists and is not open
   '#End If
   'Set rngNew = wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1") ' Starts in A1; or could put title here
   Set rngNew = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") ' Starts in A1; or could put title here

   For Each c In rngWatch                   ' Each value in rngWatch
       On Error Resume Next                 ' Interrupt Error checking
       If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match( _
           c.Value, rngReconcile, 0)) Then  ' If not in rngReconcile
           rngNew.FormulaR1C1 = c.Value     ' Copy to rngNew
           Set rngNew = rngNew(2)           ' Moves range down =Offset(rngNew,1,0)
       End If
       On Error GoTo 0                      ' Reset Error checking
       If (c.Row + 1) Mod 100 = 0 Then      'optional - Update user
           Application.StatusBar = "Evaluating cell " & c(2).Address & "..."
       End If
   Next c

   Application.StatusBar = False
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar ' Reset Status Bar
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True           ' Very important: turn this back on!

   ActiveWindow.Close Savechanges:=False       ' Not sure why this was here, but...

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful. I would like to clarify further. There are only 2 workbooks in my ideal scenario. The activeworkbook, which the code is stored in, is open at all times. We would then run the macro through the activeworkbook which would open `wbDirty` and resume your code. The code currently stops at `New_path = Client_watchlist.Names("ResultPath").RefersToRange.Value` -- I added the 'ResultPath' named range to the activeworkbook, now I receive a type mismatch error. Hovering over the `New_Path` variable shows `New_Path = ""`

Comment: So in that case, you shouldn't even need the 'ResultPath' named range. I made some changes to the code above (commenting out obsolete portions to provide some continuity), but this should work for the 2 workbook scenario you described.

Comment: I added another variable following your convention. I would like the unique value found through the for loop to be added to the end of `rngNew` as so I defined another long variable and incorporated as such `yrow = rngNew(rngNew.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row`
`Set rngNew = Range(rngNew(1), rngNew(yrow))` But now I believe I need to incorporate this range into the the for loop, preferably altering the `R1C1` formula?

Comment: Ah, you want to add to col A as new data comes in. rngNew begins as a single cell, so you can keep For loop the same. Just before For loop, do either this: `yrow = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")(rngNew.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row`  `Set rngNew = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")(yrow+1) 'Add DIM` **OR** `Set rngNew = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")(rngNew.Cells.Count).End(xlUp)(2)` The parens in Range(x) always stack *down* the column for a single cell range. If last filled cell=A125: `Range("A:A")(rngNew.Cells.Count)` is A1048576 `Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)` is A125  (filled) `Range("A125")(2)` is A126 (blank)

Answer (score 0):

I went a different direction...
Problem you had was the i in your code was the value of the cell, so when you put it into the rngReconcile.Cells(i, 1).Value call, you were putting in the text instead of the row number.

Next problem you were going to hit was that you were only checking each row for row... I believe you need a solution to check each value in column A with each value in column K.

I think I cleaned it up enough for you to use... I did reduce it just to use one sheet to get it working, so if this is what you want, I will let you put it back to multi workbooks... Hopefully you can follow it.

```
Dim last_cell As Integer
rngWatch_last_cell = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
rngReconcile_last_cell = Sheets(1).Range("K65536").End(xlUp).Row


Dim rngWatch_var As Integer, rngReconcile_var As Integer
rngWatch_var = 1
rngReconcile_var = 1

Dim i As Variant
Dim found As Integer

For rngWatch_var = 1 To rngWatch_last_cell
    Dim c As Variant
    c = rngWatch.Cells(rngWatch_var, 1).Value
    found = 0
    For rngReconcile_var = 1 To rngReconcile_last_cell
        If c = rngReconcile.Cells(rngReconcile_var, 1).Value Then
           found = 1
        End If
    Next rngReconcile_var

    If found = 0 Then
        MsgBox c & " not found in list"
        ' add to another column
    End If

Next rngWatch_var
```

Comment: there is a type mismatch error with `For rngWatch_var = 1 To rngWatch_last_cell`

Comment: They are both integers, don't see how. Debug the error, and put your mouse over rngWatch_var and rngWatch_last_cell and see what they say

Comment: Um, actually, rngWatch_var is a Variant. The syntax for declaring multiple integers on the same line would be this:
    Dim rngWatch_var As Integer, rngReconcile_var As Integer
[Dim Statement](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080007918&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=14&tl=2&pid=CH080007907&CTT=4)

Comment: Of course, Thanks Glenn. (interesting that it worked when i tested it)

Comment: Is rngWatch_last_cell a range and not an integer?

Comment: Nope, 'rngWatch_last_cell = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row' sets it to the row number of the last cell filled in